# Python AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_json' when using Windows not Mac

Tags: python, json, macos, python-2.7, pandas

When the Python code runs on Mac OSX, it works fine. However when it runs on Windows, it throws the following error, where `fruits` is a `pandas.DataFrame`.

**Code**

```
for i, row in fruits.T.iterkv():
    data = json.loads(row.to_json())
```

**Error:**

`AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_json'`

What is causing this error?

Windows system is running Python 2.7.5 with pandas v0.11.0. Mac OSX is running 2.7.2 with pandas v0.12.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API is changed in v0.12.0.

According to [What's new - v0.12.0 (July 24, 2013)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew.html#v0-12-0-july-24-2013):

> ### v0.12.0 (July 24, 2013)
>
> ...
>
> The I/O API is now much more consistent with a set of top level reader
>   functions accessed like pd.read_csv() that generally return a pandas
>   object.
>
> - read_csv
> - read_excel
> - read_hdf
> - read_sql
> - read_json
> - read_html
> - read_stata
> - read_clipboard
>
> The corresponding writer functions are object methods that are
>   accessed like df.to_csv()
>
> - to_csv
> - to_excel
> - to_hdf
> - to_sql
> - **to_json**
> - to_html
> - to_stata
> - to_clipboard